# How can I access blocked Yahoomail in my office?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols

Actually My network administrator blocked the **www.yahoomail.com** in my office. But i need to access it to read some important mails. Is there any possibilities?

I tried it by some third party website. After entering login credentials (***username and password***). I got an error "**This page requires that you have Javascript enabled on your browser.**"

But it is already enabled in my browser.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: he blocked it for a reason! if you try bypassing ! more chances you get caught! anyways a tip, try searching for "proxy avoidance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have way to access Yahoomail but I think you should just ask Admin or your teamleader or PM to allow you to use Yahoomail at work.

If you get caught while trying to connect Yahoomail without permision, its gotta be worse :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install TOR -> https://www.torproject.org/

It sends your requests over some proxies and so it should help to reached the blocked site.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most commonly used method is to use Proxy server specially the russians one